# Anomaly detection of categorical data with Isolation Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Im wondering is it possible to detect outliers in categorical data.
for example if I have list :

```
l = ['fresh','good','nice','great','amazing','bad','tasty','funny','dirty']
```

Outlier in this list would be strings `'bad'` and `'dirty'`.

If for example I have data of 10000 rows, and each row is sentence between 2 and 10 words, is it possible to detect outliers with `Isolation forest` algorithm?
What encoder should I use?
Also, I get an error when Im try to run code, error is in this line:

```
    input_par = encoder.transform([val])
```

This is the sample code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder, StandardScaler

l = ['fresh','good','nice','great','amazing','bad','tasty','funny','dirty',
'I love you', 'you are great', 'this is wrong', 'terrible']

df = pd.DataFrame({'my text': l})
x = df

# Transform the features
encoder = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['my text'])], remainder='passthrough')
x = encoder.fit_transform(x)

isolation_forest = IsolationForest(contamination = 'auto', behaviour = 'new')
model = isolation_forest.fit(x)

list_of_val = ['i love this', 'catastrophic', 'no']

for val in list_of_val:

    input_par = encoder.transform([val])

    outlier = model.predict(input_par)
    #print(outlier)

    if outlier[0] == -1:
        print('Values', val, 'are outliers')

    else:
        print('Values', val, 'are not outliers')
```

Comment: hello, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, im trying but I did not find anything

Comment: You get an error here - "input_par = encoder.transform([val])" since you're trying to pass a list and not a dataframe as "x = encoder.fit_transform(x)", maybe you should try that..
During transformation, it expects a similar kind of object.